# FLV container. How to add mp3 as audio track?

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, flv, containers

So I have an mp3 file. I have some frames inserted. Now I Need to insert this track as flv sound. How to du such thing (for frames insert I use this class http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/ )

Answer (score 0):

This class explicitly doesn't support sound. I guess if you're creating the FLV dynamically it can't be too long so maybe it's worth just playing a sound on the side with the [Sound](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html) object ?

Comment: No - I need thisto SAVE file to users HardDrive after recording. And I wont it ti be FLV. So Is there any way of making that class support Audio?